# ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for strided_slice

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run the following piece of code

```
import tensorflow as tf


def compute_area(sides):
    a = sides[:, 0]
    b = sides[:, 1]
    c = sides[:, 2]
    # Heron formula
    s = (a + b + c) * 0.5
    area_sq = s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)
    return tf.sqrt(area_sq)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    area = compute_area(tf.constant([5.0, 3.0, 7.1]))
    result = sess.run(area)
    print(result)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [3], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1>.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[5.0, 3.0, 7.1]` is a vector, which is a 1D tensor. Vectors cannot be sliced or indexed using the syntax for matrices, e.g. using `[:, 0]`, but, to access the first element of the vector, you need to (simply) use `[0]`. So, your code would work as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf


def compute_area(sides):
    a, b, c = sides[0], sides[1], sides[2]
    # Heron formula
    s = (a + b + c) * 0.5
    area_sq = s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)
    return tf.sqrt(area_sq)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    area = compute_area(tf.constant([5.0, 3.0, 7.1]))
    result = sess.run(area)
    print(result)
```

In the section "*[Referring to tf.Tensor slices](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors)*" (of the official TensorFlow article regarding tensors), you have more info regarding indexing and slicing tensors in TensorFlow.